# Should I edit out unnecessary "sorry, thanks", etc. from questions?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184414/easiest-way-to-get-appdata-path-variable-in-python) about getting `%appdata%` in Python, the user asks this:

> Sorry if this is a redundant question, writing a Python file that
>   needs to pull from the `%APPDATA%` directory. What is the easiest way to
>   find the path to this folder?

Should I edit it to something like this?

> What's the easiest way to get the path to the `%APPDATA%` directory in Python?

Comment: Yes of course, and after that find an obvious duplicate since you're editing it into a one-liner which has google-knows written all over it :)